# Android - unwanted submenu appearing after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have created very simple demo project to demonstrate the bug:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MenuBugActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_bug_demo, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Main layout - main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Menu items options_bug_demo.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_bug"
        android:title="Bug"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_bug_demo"
                android:title="Bug demo">
                <menu>
                    <item android:title="Settings"/>
                </menu>
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

1.Clicking on "Preferences" icon:
[image: Clicking "Preferences" icon]
2.Clicking on "Bug demo":
[image: Clicking on "Bug demo"]
3.Clicking on "Settings":
[image: Clicking on "Settings"]
4.Changing screen orientation to the horizontal:
[image: Changing screen orientation to the horizontal]

Submenu "Settings" (closed at step 3) appears again after screen rotation! The only way to prevent the submenu from appearing after rotation - to remove string

```
android:id="@+id/menu_bug_demo"
```

from resource file options_bug_demo.xml

**The question is how to avoid this unwanted behaviour of the submenu?**

P.S. The bug was observed on 4.0.4 and 4.1.1 and was **not** observed on 4.4.2